# How to send E-mail to user using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I was try to send message from contact-form to user's email
I get always 405 method not allowed problem from debugger I installed Wampp
so far no problem but I get no reaction what is missing I use php mail function.

what should I do send message to user ? I use
php jquery js

I want to use php and jquery Ajax. How can I check php codeblock accuracy
because no reaction from on page

Thanks for helping me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="info.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta
    name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"
  />

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#btn').click(function () {

        let message = {
          name: $("#form-name").val(),
          mail: $("#form-mail").val(),
          subject: $("#form-subject").val(),
          msg: $("#form-msg").val(),
        }

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url:  'mail.php',
          data: message,
          success: function () {
            $('.success').fadeIn(1000)
            alert("good");
          }
        })
      })

      //alert("message has been send by you");
    })
  </script>

  <body>
    <title>information</title>
    <div class="Main-container">
      <div class="container">
        <h2><b>Contact Me</b></h2>
        <div class="container-cover">
          <form class="contact-form" id=" myform" onsubmit="return false;" action="">
            <div class="inner-column-1">
              <div class="form-container">
                <b><label for="name">Name:</label></b>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="form-name"
                  class="inner-column-1"
                  placeholder="Enter Name "
                />
                <b><label for="mail">Mail:</label></b>
                <input
                  type="mail"
                  id="form-mail"
                  class="inner-column-1"
                  placeholder="Enter Email  "
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="inner-column-1">
              <b><label for="subject">Subject:</label></b>
              <input
                type="subject"
                id="form-subject"
                placeholder="Subject"
                class="inner-column-1"
                style="width: 370px;"
              />
            </div>

            <div class="inner-column-1">
              <div class="inner-column-1">
                <textarea
                  name="msg"
                  id="form-msg"
                  type="msg"
                  cols="31"
                  rows="10"
                  placeholder="Enter Something Please..."
                  style="
                    border-radius: 6px;
                    font-size: 25px;
                    border: 2px ridge royalblue;
                    overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
                    resize: none;
                  "
                ></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="inner-column-2">
              <button id="btn">Send Me</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</head>

<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization");


if ($_POST) {
  $myMail = 'blabla@gmail.com';
  $name = $_POST(['form-name']);
  $mail = $_POST(['form-mail']);
  $subject =$_POST(['form-subject']);
  $msg = $_POST(['form-msg']);
  $sender = "From:".$name."<".$mail.">"; 


 $send=mail($myMail, $subject, $msg, $sender);
 echo ($send) ? 'success' : 'error';
}
?>
```

Comment: I would have the mail processing in a separate script that only does that. What does the developer console show when you execute this as is?

Comment: @user3783243 Normally I store  in the external file I wrote for showing

Comment: You could make an ajax request to a php file on the server and send the email to the user using the mail function

Comment: Did not I do it ?  @natre214

Answer (score 1):

You have nested form tags which is a bad idea - just make it a single one and move the class into it.

```
  <form action="mail.php" method="POST">
        <form class="contact-form"> 
        <!-- get rid of this inner form tag -->
```

Forms (by default) submit and load (or reload) a page. You are using ajax so you must suppress that natural behavior. The simplest way is just an inline event - and you can get rid of `method` and `action` since they're not needed here:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;" class="contact-form">
```

I agree with the comment - the PHP script would make alot more sense as a separate file. Also, you should consider outputting if it was successful or not.

```
...
$done = mail("blabla@gmail.com", 'This is an email from:', $msg, $mail);
echo $done ? "success" : "fail" ;
```

That way your ajax can get the response and report it back to the user

Comment: You need to run an actual webserver locally @01d . Accessing php files via `file://` won't  run them through the PhP interpreter so they won't execute. Additionally, JS is restricted in most browsers on `file://` protocols and won't run or will face security limitations that prevent it from doing what you want.